# Momentum with respect to a non-straight axis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

For a tetrahedron, we place the mass with the weight vector $(0,0,g)$ in each vertex.

The mass center is at $m=\frac{1}{4}(A+B+C+D)$ where ABCD are the vertices.

Find $a$ such that that the total momentum of the weights with respect to the axis going through the origin $(0,0,0)$, and which has the directional vector $\vec{v} = (a,2,0)$, is zero.

---

I don't quite understand. What is the total momentum? How can I find $a$? And if the axis is not straight, then isn't the momentum different depending on what *point* on the axis you measure against?

Comment: After your recent edit, it says "... say we have the *weight* $(0,0,g)$..." instead of the previous "... say we have the *momentum* $(0,0,g)$..." which makes no sense to me. A weight is a scalar, not a vector...

Comment: Your original wording was fine, I think. In any case, it was better than the subsequent edits - weights are *not* vectors, but momentums are. Anyway - I think what they want you to do is to compute the total momentum, and then chose an axis which is perpendicular to the total momentum vector. The momentum in direction of that axis will than be zero.

Comment: Hm, I'm confused. I'd have said that the total momentum is simply the sum of the individual masses' mometums, but then - as you said - the total momentum were $(0,0,4g)$ which is perpendicular to $(a,2,0)$ for *every* $a$, so that can't be right...

Comment: Can you define what momentum with respect to an axis is?

Comment: I really don't know. The author didn't explain it at all.